# IntelliJ 13 JSF Taglib support in xhtml file is not working

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, intellij-idea, xhtml, taglib

I have the following scenario:

1. Custom defined tag lib with xhtml-based components (without a java class)
2. It works
3. IntelliJ completes the component name like `<example:myComponent />` but the the attribute like `label`
4. If I cmd+click (ctrl+click) the component, IntelliJ will jump to the taglib configuration file but not the the component source (.xhtml)
5. The resource link in the taglib file is not clickable.

If I use only a resource folder without tag lib, everything is highlighted correctly.
Is there a mistake by myself or is this behavior 'correct'? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my misunderstanding of how a tag lib works.
You have tod define all parameter in the tag lib as well as in the component.
If you do this, IntelliJ will autocomplete the attributes.